# Encountered a problem with rrousselGit / provider

Tags: flutter, dart

When I was running the app, the first time HomeNewsPage became a red page, 
the console showed an error message, about 1 second, HomeNewsPage returned to normal and I got the data from the HomeProvider.
I have been looking for a long time why I didn't find why, 
please Help me to look at the code, my english is not very good ，thank you very much,

and also

HomeProvider provider = Provider.of(context, **listen: false**);

set the listen=true   _HomeNewsPageBuildState  # **build()**  Method will be executed two times

set the listen=true   _HomeNewsPageBuildState  # **build()**  Method will be executed one times

I do not know why

#### This is the Page

```
class HomeNewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    HomeProvider provider = Provider.of<HomeProvider>(context, listen: false);
    return _HomeNewsPageBuild(provider);
  }
}

class _HomeNewsPageBuild extends StatefulWidget {
  final HomeProvider provider;
  _HomeNewsPageBuild(this.provider);
  @override
  _HomeNewsPageBuildState createState() => _HomeNewsPageBuildState();
}


class _HomeNewsPageBuildState extends State<_HomeNewsPageBuild> {
  HomeProvider _provide;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('HomeNewsPage initState');
    _provide ??= widget.provider;
    getHomeNewsList(_provide);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print("HomeNewsPage--build");
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: UniteColors.bg_color,
      body: _initView(),
    );
  }

  Consumer<HomeProvider> _initView() {
    return Consumer<HomeProvider>(
      builder: (_, HomeProvider value, __) {
        return _provide.newsList.length > 0 ? _buildListView() : UiHelper.initLoading(false);
      },
    );
  }

 Widget _buildListView() {
    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        _newsBigItem(),
        Divider(height: 1.0, color: UniteColors.divider_color),
        _newsSmallItem(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

#### This is the HomeProvider

```
class HomeProvider extends BaseProvider {
  final HomeRepo _homeRepo = HomeRepo();

  List<DataList> _newsList;

  List<DataList> get newsList => _newsList;

  set newsList(List<DataList> value) {
    _newsList = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  ///GetNewsListData
  Observable getHomeNewsList() => _homeRepo
      .getHomeNewsList()
      .doOnData((result) {
        var data = json.decode(result.toString());
        HomeEntity homeEntity = EntityFactory.generateOBJ(data);
        this.newsList = homeEntity.dataList;
      })
      .doOnError((e) {
        print(e.toString());
      })
      .doOnListen(() =>{})
      .doOnDone(() =>{});
}
```

#### This is the error message

```
 I/flutter: HomeNewsPage initState
 I/flutter: doOnListen
 I/flutter: HomeNewsPage--build
 I/flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
 I/flutter: The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building Consumer<HomeProvider> 
 (dirty, dependencies:
 I/flutter: [InheritedProvider<HomeProvider>]):
 I/flutter: The getter 'length' was called on null.
 I/flutter: Receiver: null
 I/flutter: Tried calling: length
 I/flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:

 I/flutter: #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:50:5)
 I/flutter: #1      _HomeNewsPageBuildState._initView.<anonymous closure> (package:pear_video/app/pages/home/home_news_page.dart:48:34)
 I/flutter: #2      Consumer.build (package:provider/src/consumer.dart:47:12)
 I/flutter: #3      StatelessElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3885:28)
 I/flutter: #4      ComponentElement.performRebuild 
      (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3835:15)
 #5..............
 #6................
......
```

Comment: Seems like `_initView` is called before `initState`, so your `_provide.newsList.length` line crashes out?  Just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the value of `newsList` is `null`, that is when you get the error because `null` has no property named `length` hence `The getter 'length' was called on null.` error.

After calling `getHomeNewsList` which probably is calling an api, which also takes some time, after which it assigns a `List` value to `_newsList`.

Now your UI is re-rendered where `newList` returns a `List` which has a property called length.

One way to not get that initial error is to initialize `_newsList` with an empty `List`.

```
List<DataList> _newsList = [];
```